# No keyserver available

Tags: keyserver

I want to install JDK 8, but during the execution of this command

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

I got this error

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmplvej9x_g/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

What a have to do? I'm new in linux.

Nota: I have proxy in my network and I did some configurations

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this PPA is long dead

Answer (score 0):

I got this error trying to update to mono 6, I solved it by switching from keyserver.ubuntu.com to keys.gnupg.net